# GeoServer GeoTIFF rendering skips data between Greenwich and the Dateline

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I've got a custom web application using OpenLayers3 running GeoServer (2.7.1) as a back-end.  I've added a world-wide temperature GeoTIFF as a test, and it renders in [a strange way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E72J3.jpg).

[image]

If I move the map to pan eastward, the GeoTIFF fully renders over the entire map.  If I move the map to pan westward, the image only covers half the world.  The full world coverage starts about half way across North America.

Has anyone seen this before?  What am I doing wrong that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Strange, aside from reporting you can try with disabling advanced projection handling with adding -DENABLE_ADVANCED_PROJECTION=false to the startup options.

Comment: That makes the TIFF show up only on one section of the world map that spans from Greenwich to Greenwich.  Where the map repeats left and right over and over, it's workable, but not ideal.

Comment: I would try with a more recent release of the 2.7.x series. If the problem still applies I would report it to the ML alongside the originating Geotiff.

Comment: Same problem with 2.7.2, and the 2.8-beta doesn't even render the TIFF properly

Comment: Well, I would suggest to open a bug report adding some test data.

Comment: I'm concerned the GeoTIFF isn't well formed...  I've been playing with changing it from 0 to 360 to be -180 to 180, and it renders more favourably with -180 to 180.  Well enough for a demo, anyway.  If I change it to contain -360 to 0, the opposite half of the globe doesn't render.  Updating OL3 to 3.9.0 makes the unrendered portions consistent when scrolling west and east.

Comment: Ah wait, a geotiff that goes from 0 to 360 is currently unsupported in GS although we are working on it so things should change in a short time :)

If you pushed it back to +-180 it should work fine.

Comment: Good to know!  We did, and the tiles closeset to the dateline don't render. As you zoom in, this area gets smaller and smaller. I was going to suggest he make it from -179.95 to 179.95 instead of starting right on -180.